# MDI open tab on item drag

Tags: vb.net, mdi, mdichild

so I'm having some trouble with opening the tab to where I want to drag some data.

I have 2 child MDI forms, with both a listview.
I would like to drag a listviewitem from mdichild 1 to mdichild 2.

The problem is that I am not able to find the correct event that makes it possible to SHOW the second form when I drag my data to the corresponding MDI tab.

Right now the only thing I get when I drag data to a MDI tab is the standard black circle with a stripe through it.

Any ideas on how to open the tab?

All help is appreciated

Comment: Have you checked that the `AllowDrop` property is true for the target?

Comment: Yes, but the tab doesn't belong to the target form it seems.

Comment: Is the MDIChild form's `AllowDrop` property true?

Comment: Yes. I can detect a dragover in the MDI now, but this gets triggerd as soon as i leave my first listview, not when I hover a tab

Comment: Perhaps show some code, then.  You have to handle all of the drag events properly for this to work.  Show us what you have so far - specifically what is in the `ItemDrag`, `DragEnter`, `DragDrop`, etc, handlers for the relevant controls.

Comment: I don't have any relevant code, because nothing works as it should.
In the itemdrag, I set the data to drag to a listviewcollection.

In the dragenter, I have no idea what to put there.. Here i should detect if another tab is hovered on or not, but I have no clue how to do so. The dragdrop is something I have written a couple of times so that won't be a problem.

Comment: You have to document what your MDI "Tab" is.  Code, screen shot, etc.

Comment: when I'm back at the office

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without code where you problem is, but could it be as simple as this?

```
Private Sub MDIChildForm_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As _
              System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragEnter
    Me.Activate()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub
```

This will un-minimize and activate the child form when you drag over it.  This is assuming your "Tab" is a minimized MDI child form...

Comment: Well, 
The problem is that the DragEnter event isn't fired when I hover the tab nor does the corresponding form open when the tab is hovered. That's where I'm stuck.
I'll try to add some code when I'm back at the office.